# How can I get value of Medicine inside prescription from the response body as given below in Rest Assured?

Tags: java, json, arraylist, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

```
[
    {
        "id": "abd88c05-2919-45f2-b1d0-c99af140bbb0",
        "order_id": "2ddc8302-34e0-437c-8e77-0e0ca80c18ad",
        "user_id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001",
        "prescription": "{\"prescription\":[{\"Dosage\":\"2-0-2\",\"Medicine\":\"Hair Ras\",\"composition\":\"\",\"description\":\"Boosts blood circulation to hair follicles\",\"info\":\"Take after meals\",\"is_recommended\":false,\"quantity\":\"2\",\"type\":\"ayurveda\"}]}",
        "created_at": "2022-10-14T13:43:47.039Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-10-14T13:43:47.039Z",
        ...
    }
]
```

---

```java
JsonPath js_prescrition = newJsonPath(response_prescription);
Object prescription = js_prescrition.get("prescription");
JsonPath js_prescrition1 = new JsonPath("prescription");
String medicine = js_prescrition.get("Medicine");
System.out.println(medicine);
```

Comment: The current state of the question is very poor, consider improving it. Firstly, please describe what have you tried? Share your **code-attempt** and describe the issue you've encountered. Secondly, **simplify** your JSON. Use *edit* button or this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74071620/edit).

Comment: Read [ask] and edit the question to make it more answerable. The amount of effort you put into asking the question is directly related to the quality of answers you will get.

Comment: [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

This code would help you

```
String data = given()...asString();
String prescription = JsonPath.from(data).getString("[0].prescription").replaceAll("\\\\", "");
List<Map<String, ?>> nested = JsonPath.from(prescription).get("prescription");
String medicine = (String) nested.get(0).get("Medicine");
System.out.println(medicine);
//Hair Ras
```

Answer (score 0):

Library *Josson* can do it in a short query statement.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "[" +
    "    {" +
    "        \"id\": \"abd88c05-2919-45f2-b1d0-c99af140bbb0\"," +
    "        \"order_id\": \"2ddc8302-34e0-437c-8e77-0e0ca80c18ad\"," +
    "        \"user_id\": \"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001\"," +
    "        \"prescription\": \"{\\\"prescription\\\":[{\\\"Dosage\\\":\\\"2-0-2\\\",\\\"Medicine\\\":\\\"Hair Ras\\\",\\\"composition\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"description\\\":\\\"Boosts blood circulation to hair follicles\\\",\\\"info\\\":\\\"Take after meals\\\",\\\"is_recommended\\\":false,\\\"quantity\\\":\\\"2\\\",\\\"type\\\":\\\"ayurveda\\\"}]}\"," +
    "        \"created_at\": \"2022-10-14T13:43:47.039Z\"," +
    "        \"updated_at\": \"2022-10-14T13:43:47.039Z\"" +
    "    }" +
    "]");
    
String medicine = josson.getString("[0].json(prescription).prescription[0].Medicine");
System.out.println(medicine);
```